# Assigning a column value from one data frame to another in R

Tags: r

I have created an empty data frame using another data frame with the below code.

```
compare<-data.frame(nrow=nrow(test_email),ncol=ncol(test_data))
colnames(compare)<-c("email", "gender")
```

Now, I am trying to assign value to the columns of compare data frame based on some conditions using simple assignment statement.

```
compare[1,1]<-test_email[1,1]
compare[1,2]<-test_data[1,2]
```

In the above, `test_email[1,1]` has an email ID like"abc@gmail.com"
But, after assignment `compare[1,1]` has value 81 and not the email ID. 
I am not able to get it why the email is not getting assigned and some numeric vlaue is getting assigned. Can anyone let me know this reason and how to solve. Structure of test_email is below:

```
structure(list(email = structure(c(81L, 75L, 57L, 61L, 79L, 76L),
.Label = "ajay.bansal@siemens.com", "amanmeet.bhalla@gmail.com",
"aoneshp@gmail.com", "aparna_anand@msn.com", "ar.ashwani@gmail.com",
"ar.parulbansal@gmail.com", "ar.preet02@gmail.com",
"asdawsd@yahoo.com", "assd@yopmail.com",
"avijeet_yadav@rediffmail.com", "avneng1.negi@gmail.com",
"avnihatnagar@yahoo.com", "bansalanuj007@yahoo.com.au",
"bhanu5877@yahoo.co.in"), class = "factor")), .Names = "email",
w.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am not able to find out why R is converting email into some numeric values during assignment.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data using `dput()`? Based on what you've written, it seems like you've entered your email IDs as factors (or R has automatically converted them to factors, which it generally does with strings unless you tell it not to).

Comment: test_email<-sqlQuery(channel, "select distinct email from abc limit 100");
test_data<-sqlQuery(channel, "select * from pqr");
Then I just created an empty data frame and then I am trying to assign it values from the above 2 created data frames test_email and test_data. But, its converting them into numeric. Please find the sample data                 
              email
1      shweta.katta@jasperindia.com
2        sanjaykhanna99@hotmail.com
3               neoneo006@gmail.com
test_data:
                 name        gender
87               Aanand      M
88        Aanandaswarup      M

Comment: Maybe `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` helps. See `?data.frame`.

Comment: @KunalBatra, sample data pasted into your comment like this is not very helpful. Please use something like `dput(head(--dataset--))` to at least show us the first few lines of your data. Using this approach will retain any modifications R has made to your data when reading it in (for example, factor conversions). [This is (well, should be) mandatory reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I added this option while creating compare data frame as below.

compare<-data.frame(nrow=nrow(test_email),ncol=ncol(test_data),stringsAsFactors=FALSE);

but, it did not help..

Comment: @mrdwab:
structure(list(email = structure(c(81L, 75L, 57L, 61L, 79L, 76L
), .Label = c("ajay.bansal@siemens.com", "amanmeet.bhalla@gmail.com", 
"aoneshp@gmail.com", "aparna_anand@msn.com", "ar.ashwani@gmail.com", 
"ar.parulbansal@gmail.com", "ar.preet02@gmail.com", "asdawsd@yahoo.com", .Names = "email", row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

hope this helps

Comment: Can you edit your question and add this information there?

Comment: Can anyone please let me know what can be done to prevent this conversion from string to numeric..

Comment: I think `as.character(test_email[1,1])` should do the trick. You should check the structure you posted for `test_email` by the way, there is something wrong with it. You probably mis-copied it.

Comment: To prevent it though, you could probably have written your data.frame directly with the data as follows `compare <- data.frame(email=test_email, gender=test_data[,2])`.

Comment: Try `dput` again.  The code you provided here and above are missing elements.  If it's too big use `dput(head(test_email))` and copy that output directly to here.  Then use code tags to wrap it as you did your other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assignment is still reading the email addresses as factors.

A simple approach to this would be:

```
compare[1,1] <- as.character(test_email[1,1])
```