# Replacing values in tbl_df

Tags: r

I have a data frame which looks like this

```
>data
Source: local data frame [10 x 10]

           CHANNEL SALES ACTUAL_SPEND ACTUAL_RETURNS SPEND_SCENARIO RETURNS_SCENARIO LB  UB Spend_Diff
1           Cinema  1324    298.56482       8.639514      298.56482         8.639514 80 120          0
2  Digital Display   924    604.29080      12.291163      604.29080        12.291163 80 120          0
3         Magazine  1164    276.62779       8.316066      276.62779         8.316066 80 120          0
4          Outdoor  1004    570.15592      11.938969      570.15592        11.938969 80 120          0
5      Paid Search  1404     82.02715       4.528442       82.02715         4.528442 80 120          0
6            Press  1084    524.82576      11.454538      524.82576        11.454538 80 120          0
7            Radio  1564    523.72771      11.442549      523.72771        11.442549 80 120          0
8   TV-Free to Air   844   1346.55335      18.347707     1346.55335        18.347707 80 120          0
9   TV-Infomercial  1484    336.86113       9.176888      336.86113         9.176888 80 120          0
10       TV-Pay TV  1244    340.21096       9.222404      340.21096         9.222404 80 120          0
Variables not shown: Returns_Diff (dbl)
```

I want to replace values inside this tbl_df object. I tried this

```
>data[1,1]<-"abc"
```

However it doesnt seem to work. Any help will be greatly appreciated

**EDIT**
Adding the str of the data set and showing no change in value after assignment

```
 print(str(data))
        Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   10 obs. of  10 variables:
     $ CHANNEL         : Factor w/ 10 levels "Cinema","Digital Display",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
     $ SALES           : int  1324 924 1164 1004 1404 1084 1564 844 1484 1244
     $ ACTUAL_SPEND    : num  299 604 277 570 82 ...
     $ ACTUAL_RETURNS  : num  8.64 12.29 8.32 11.94 4.53 ...
     $ SPEND_SCENARIO  : num  299 604 277 570 82 ...
     $ RETURNS_SCENARIO: num  8.64 12.29 8.32 11.94 4.53 ...
     $ LB              : num  80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80
     $ UB              : num  120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120
     $ Spend_Diff      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     $ Returns_Diff    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    NULL
    data[1,1] == "A"
    print(data)



   Source: local data frame [10 x 10]

           CHANNEL SALES ACTUAL_SPEND ACTUAL_RETURNS SPEND_SCENARIO RETURNS_SCENARIO LB  UB Spend_Diff
1           Cinema  1324    298.56482       8.639514      298.56482         8.639514 80 120          0
2  Digital Display   924    604.29080      12.291163      604.29080        12.291163 80 120          0
3         Magazine  1164    276.62779       8.316066      276.62779         8.316066 80 120          0
4          Outdoor  1004    570.15592      11.938969      570.15592        11.938969 80 120          0
5      Paid Search  1404     82.02715       4.528442       82.02715         4.528442 80 120          0
6            Press  1084    524.82576      11.454538      524.82576        11.454538 80 120          0
7            Radio  1564    523.72771      11.442549      523.72771        11.442549 80 120          0
8   TV-Free to Air   844   1346.55335      18.347707     1346.55335        18.347707 80 120          0
9   TV-Infomercial  1484    336.86113       9.176888      336.86113         9.176888 80 120          0
10       TV-Pay TV  1244    340.21096       9.222404      340.21096         9.222404 80 120          0
Variables not shown: Returns_Diff (dbl)
```

Comment: The value remains unchanged for the row and column specified

Comment: I have added more details

Comment: `data[1,1] == "A"` this is not an assingment.

Comment: Now from the output of `str()`is clear: it is the same problem as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949613/assigning-a-column-value-from-one-data-frame-to-another-in-r/11977468#11977468

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first column of your dataframe is a factor:

```
> f <- factor(c("a", "b", "c"))
> f
[1] a b c
Levels: a b c
> f[1] <- "xyz"
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, 1, value = "xyz") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
> f
[1] <NA> b    c   
Levels: a b c
```

There must be the same warning message on your terminal. Convert the factor:

```
data$CHANNEL <- as.character(data$CHANNEL)
```

and the assignment `data[1,1] <- "abc"` will work.